# Add action to PyCharm editor context menu passing pattern of interest

Tags: pycharm, contextmenu

Through settings of PyCharm it is possible to add new actions to PyCharms editor context menu. Is it possible to pass the pattern that was selected, when the context menu was opened, to a custom action?

Specifically what i want to achieve is: I want to click on a pattern of interest in any source code file and find occurances in the project by using a custom regex in connection with that pattern of interest.